# How to compare two string in javascript neglecting character arrangement

Tags: javascript, string, comparison

Hi I need to compare two string but without seeing the arrangement

like if string1 is

```
var a="apple#1;banana#2;orange#3"
```

and String2 is

```
var b="banana#2;orange#3;apple#1"
```

a.compare(b) should gives true as values are same just arrangement are different

```
if(!a.compare(b)){
alert("not matched");
}
else{
alert("matched");
}
```

I did one but its too much lengthy code I'm sharing it here:

```
function ReturnCollection (str){

                var arr=str.split(';');

                var returnarr=[];
                for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){

                    var indx=arr[i].indexOf('#');
                    var text=arr[i].substr(0,indx);
                    var val=arr[i].substr(indx+1);
                    returnarr.push([text,val]);

                }
                return returnarr;
            }

function Matching(){
    var afinal=ReturnCollection(a);
    var bfinal=ReturnCollection(b);
    bflag=false;
    outerloop:
     for(i=0;i<afinal.length;i++){
         for(j=0;j<bfinal.length;j++){
             if(bfinal[j][1] === afinal[i][1]){
                   continue outerloop;
               }
              }

             bflag=true;
             break outerloop;
           }

       if(bflag){
             alert("not matched");
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean actual character arrangement or item arrangement? With neglecting character arrangement `"annaba#1;norage#2;pleap#3"` would match.

Comment: no first will be ok apple will be apple but after # there is uniqueidentifier so have to match that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Rob is on the right path, but I would split it on the semicolon:

```
var a="apple#1;banana#2;orange#3";
var b="banana#2;orange#3;apple#1" 

console.log(a.split(";").sort().join(";") === b.split(";").sort().join(";"));
```

because if you just split it on an empty string, you would get an array of characters but what you really want is an array of words, otherwise you this would be true as well:

```
var a = "apple#1;bananas#2;orange#3";
var b = "banana#2;orranges#3;apple#1";

console.log(a.split(";").sort().join(";") === b.split(";").sort().join(";")); //false
console.log(a.split("").sort().join("") === b.split("").sort().join("")); //true
```

Both strings have the same characters in them, but they are definitely not equivalent in the way you probably want.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a one-liner that should do the trick:

```
string.split('').sort().join('')
```

This works by turning the string into an array, sorting the array and then collapsing back to a string (sorted by characters). You can run that on both strings and compare

```
console.log(a.split('').sort().join('') == b.split('').sort().join('')) // true
```

You could use ES6 and string coercion to make it a bit more terse:

```
[...a].sort()+'' === [...b].sort()+''
```

Comment: Hi thanks I am checking this with my code if it works will let you know thanks anyways

Comment: This won't work in certain cases. See my answer below

Comment: So, `foo;bar` is "equal" to `abr;oof`?

Comment: @georg In terms of the question they asked: "Hi I need to compare two string but without seeing the arrangement", yes. They clarified at some point that the individual words had to stay in tact, but I haven't been back to the question since that happened.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're actually comparing *sets*, why not to use `Set` explicitly?

```js
var a = "apple#1;banana#2;orange#3"
var b = "banana#2;orange#3;apple#1"

var sa = new Set(a.split(';'))
var sb = new Set(b.split(';'))

areEqual = sa.size == sb.size && [...sa].every(x => sb.has(x))
console.log(areEqual)
```